# Convert date of format dd mon yyyy to return integer of month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a varchar variable containing value 01 May 2013 and I need to obtain the integer of the Month part.

for eg if 01 May 2013 is input I should get the result as 5

The query I wrote was :

```
select DATEPART(MM,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),'01 '+SUBSTRING(FISCAL_MONTH,1,3)+' 2013'),100))
FROM <table name>
```

Here FISCAL_MONTH is my column name from the table. However this query is showing me the result, for eg 11 for November but is also throwing the following error : 
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I have tried various combinations, bit in vain. Kindly note I need it in a query. Kindly help.

Comment: What flavor of SQL are you using?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Mauve ([it has the most RAM](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Database%20Color)). But probably SQL Server (from `DATEPART`)

Comment: @Jon of all Trades - Im using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2):

If that is the only date you want to convert then you can simplify the SQL statement to:

```
select datepart(mm,convert(datetime,'01 May 2013'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used this to test and it worked:

```
declare @t as varchar(333)
set @t = '01 May 2013'

select datepart(mm,convert(datetime, @t))
```

Gives me

```
5
```

If you are still getting that conversion error, then you either have some **NULL values *OR* some date values that are not in the correct format**.  Check the data in your table to see which it is.

Comment: You don't need to convert that string to a date. you can just use: `select datepart(mm,'01 May 2013')`

Comment: Oops.  I meant to put @t instead of the string in the datepart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try and then shall post my results

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it to you to add the rest of the months.

```
select case substring('01 MAY 2013',4,3) when 'JAN' then 1 
when 'FEB' then 2
when 'MAR' then 3    
when 'APR' then 4
when 'MAY' then 5 
when 'JUN' then 6 else 9999 end
```

Answer (score 0):

It might just be that there is a 3 instead of a 2 in the substring argument:

SUBSTRING(FISCAL_MONTH,1,**2**)+' 2013'),100))

The `concat`  might work also: 
    select DATEPART(MM, CONCAT('01/', substring(convert(varchar(15),'03/23/2013'),1,2),'/2013'));

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try and then shall post my results

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it is real interesting to see all the weird code that people come up with.  I use the KISS policy most of the time (keep it simple stupid).

How about the MONTH() function.  It has been in the TSQL language forever.  I even threw in a coalesce to handle any unexpected NULLS.

```
-- Simple date as text
declare @var_test varchar(20) = '01 may 2013';

-- Use coalesce to handle nulls, use month to return int
select month(coalesce(@var_test, '01 jan 1900')) as my_month_index
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try and then shall post my results

Answer (score 0):

`Select   month ( cast ( date_col  as datetime )) 
From table`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try and then shall post my results

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert with proper format, you have to pass the apprpriate format-style value on your conversion. As per MSDN, you are using "dd mon yy" format, so you have to supply the corresponding format-style-code 6 or 106

```
Declare @FISCAL_MONTH nvarchar(max) = '01 May 2013'
select datepart(mm,Convert(datetime, @FISCAL_MONTH, 6))
--5

Set @FISCAL_MONTH = '01 November 2013'
select datepart(mm,Convert(datetime, @FISCAL_MONTH, 6))
--11
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try and then shall post my results